# Receiving Error when I use Sequelize on Ubuntu 18.04. No errors happen with the same exact files on Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using an ubuntu 18.04 laptop with ATOM. When I try to use sequelizer I get this error.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an asyn
>   c function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:16986) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not
>    handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

This is in my models.js file:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// Connect to the database
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: 'sequelize_lesson',
  dialect:  'postgres',
});


// Define an Artist
const Artist = sequelize.define('artist', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
});


// Define a Record
const Record = sequelize.define('record', {
  title:           Sequelize.STRING,
  year:            Sequelize.INTEGER,
  cover_image_url: Sequelize.STRING,
});

// define the association between Artists --<< Records
// @see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK
Artist.hasMany(Record, { onDelete: 'cascade' });

// make the association from both directions
Record.belongsTo(Artist);

module.exports = {
  Artist,
  Record,
  sequelize,
};

and in the file I am trying to run resetDb.js

const { sequelize } = require('./models');

const main = async () => {
  await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  process.exit();
};

main();

//this is what I am trying to run with the command
node resetDb.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you need to using a `try/catch` or a `.catch()` since there is an exception being thrown in a Promise. Possibly just because you have `process.exit()` instead of `process.exit(0)`? In either case, use something like this to see the error:

```
const main = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    process.exit(0); // exit code 0 is normal
  } catch (err) {
    // this will show the error
    console.log('There was an error!', err);
  }
};
```